# vue table scrolling bottom function does not work on firefox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firefox, scroll

I have a third party code that updates a table dynamically and scrolls down a table when a img tag is clicked, the whole code works fine in many browsers but not in firefox, when I click the img tag that has suscribed the function called scrollDown which focus the last row of the table, it does nothing but only in that browser, I have spent so much hours trying to figure it out but with not luck at all, I don't have a lot of experience with vue, but is a mystery for me that it does not work in firefox.

this is how I suscribed the img tag with the function :

```
                        <img
                        src="../../../img/down-arrows.png"
                        class="icon-arrows-down c-pointer"
                        alt="arrow down"
                        @click="scrollDown">
```

this particular code is the one that perform on click event :

```
        scrollDown: function() {
        let parentDiv = this.$refs.table.$el.tBodies[0];
        parentDiv.scrollTop = parentDiv.scrollHeight;
    },
```

It triggers some other functions but I'm sure there is the issue.

I just added my code in a fiddle, it wont run because of lots of dependencies are omitted there, you can check: https://jsfiddle.net/175bLodz/

Comment: that jsfiddle is pointless as it's invalid

Comment: I know it's invalid, it is just to show my current code

Comment: oh "fiddle preview" suggests running code

Comment: fixed the description